# Within the context of tm::content_transformer() how would I use mgsub?

Tags: r, tm, qdap

qdap::[mgsub](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/textclean/versions/0.3.0/topics/mgsub) takes the following parameters:

```
mgsub(x, pattern, replacement)
```

Within library(tm) corpus transformation you can wrap non tm functions within `content_transformer()`, e.g.

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

Here is a data frame with some poorly spelt text:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:2,
  sometext = c("[cad] appls", "bannanas")
)
```

And here is a data frame with a custom lookup for misspelt words:

```
spldoc <- data.frame(
  incorrects = c("appls", "bnnanas"),
  corrects = c("apples", "bannanas")
)
```

Using mgsub outwith the context of corpus and content_transformer() I could just do this:

```
wrongs <- select(spldoc, incorrects)[,1] %>% paste0("\\b",.,"\\b") # prepend and append \\b to create word boundary regex
rights <- select(spldoc, corrects)[,1]
df$sometext <- mgsub(wrongs, rights, df$sometext, fixed = F)
```

But I can't see how I could write mgsub inside a function to pass to `content_transformer()` what would my parameter for x be as in mgsub(x, pattern, replacement)?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
# create separate function to pass into tm_map()

spelling_update <- content_transformer(function(x, lut) mgsub(paste0("\\b", lut[, 1], "\\b") , lut[, 2], x, fixed = F))
```

Then

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, spelling_update(spldoc))
```